# Portfolios sorted by TED volatility

Tags: beta

I was reading a paper titled "Betting against Beta" ([link](http://docs.lhpedersen.com/BettingAgainstBeta.pdf)). The paper has five major propositions. The fourth proposition is that betas are compressed towards one when funding liquidity risk is high. I am not able to understand what is the interpretation of this statement. Further, the authors have constructed three portfolios sorted by TED volatility for U.S. stocks. I was not able to understand the mechanism behind this sorting. Page 18; table 10 of the paper.

Comment: For the first question they seem to mean that beta $\beta$, is decresing in funding risk when $\beta>1$ and increasing when $\beta<1$.